# Rails 6 Remove specific error - delete(:email)

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I know I can use `user.errors.delete(: email)` to delete the email validation error, but if an email has multiple errors on it, I assume it would remove all the errors associated with email.

Do rails have a way to delete a specific error message? I would like to remove the `:already_confirmed` error only.  Looking for something like:  `user.errors.delete( email: :already_confirmed)`

```
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007feee7ab60ere8
 @base=
  #<User id: 123, email: "some@domain.com", created_at: "2020-09-26 19:00:38", updated_at: "2020-09-26 19:01:27", first_name: nil, last_name: nil>,
 @details={:email=>[{:error=>:already_confirmed}]},
 @messages={:email=>["was already confirmed, please try signing in"]}>
```

Comment: Well, it's hash. You can always try with `user.errors.delete(@details[:email][0][:error] == :already_confimed)` ... But keep in mind that I haven't tested this, but that'd be the first step I'd personally try.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard you method failed with error NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

There should really be a `user.errors.remove()` method in rails. However, this is how I did it, but I am still hoping for a cleaner way.

```
error_index = user.errors.details[:email].find_index{|i| i[:error] ==  :already_confirmed}
if error_index.present?
  user.errors.messages[:email].delete_at(error_index)
  user.errors.details[:email].delete_at(error_index)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveModel` doesn't support any interface to delete specific errors

But you can something like this:

```
errors.details[:email].reject! { |detail| detail >= { error: :taken } }
errors.messages[:email].delete(t("activerecord.errors.messages.taken"))
```

It's not very elegant. But I haven't found a more beautiful solution yet

First line contains [`Hash#>=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-3E-3D) method. It returns `true` if one hash is part of another. In the example above, the error hash (`detail`) will also have the `:value` key

Second line deletes element from array by content. You need to know error message. Use the right locale key value

Answer (score -1):

Just came across this, you can do `model.errors.clear`